# What are these odd characters appearing when I use P4Merge with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, diff, character-encoding, file-comparison

When comparing files, I get these characters at the start of the diff.

[image]
[Image of the strange characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Mqb.png)

I'm not sure exactly what more information to provide, but will be watching this question if anyone is able to help but needs more configuration information.

Answer (score 1):

That is a [Unicode Byte Order Mark or BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

It is typically found in files written on a Microsoft platform using *[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)* or *[UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) LE* encoding (which Microsoft unhelpfully describe as "Unicode")

You can normalise your files to a common encoding using tools like [`iconv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) or `recode`.

Life is likely to be a lot easier if you standardise on UTF-8 with no BOM for everything you do using text. However you may have specific circumstances that make that unattainable.

See also

- [Best way to convert text files between character sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)

Comment: `ï»¿` is **UTF-8** byte order mark as appears in code page `1252` i.e. (ANSI 1252) US & Western Eu.